# Formulário com assinatura não destaca campo obrigatório

Tags: php, javascript, html, formulário

Tenho um formulário onde tem um campo de assinatura, segue codigo:

```
  <script src="signature/jquery.signaturepad.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.sigPad').signaturePad({drawOnly:true});
    });
  </script>
  <script src="signature/assets/json2.min.js"></script>
```

Esse campo é obrigatório!
O que preciso é que ele fique assinalado em vermelho, caso alguém tente enviar o formulário sem assinar. A pessoa não consegue enviar se não assinar, mas ele não mostra, como nos outros campos, que ficam em vermelho, caso não sejam preenchido.

Resumindo, só quero colocar a borda vermelha nesse campo, para assinalar que não foi preenchido, quando for para enviar.

Segue a parte HTML

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-12 form-group">
<label for="name"> Assinatura:</label>

                                <ul class="sigNav">
                                  <li class="clearButton"><a href="#clear">Limpar</a></li>
                                </ul>
                                <div class="sig sigWrapper">
                                  <center><canvas class="pad" width="390" height="150"></canvas></center>
                                   <input required type="hidden" name="assinatura" id='assinatura' class="output">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: E como é o Html?

Comment: Atualizei, coloquei no post